# Example that Stone-Weierstraß theorem does not hold if $E$ not compact

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the Stone-Weierstraß theorem does in general not hold when $E$ is not
>   compact.
>
> *Hint:* Consider $E = \Bbb R$, construct a countable algebra $\mathcal{C}' \subset \mathcal{C}_b(\Bbb R)$ so that $\mathcal{C}'$ separates points in $\Bbb R$, then use that $\mathcal{C}_b(\Bbb R)$ is not separable.
>
> ***The Stone-Weierstraß theorem:***
>
> Let $E$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{C}_b(E;\mathbb{K})$ be an algebra that separates points. If $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$, then in addition assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under complex conjugation (that is, if $f \in \mathcal{C}$, then the complex conjugate function $f$ is also in $\mathcal{C}$).
>  Then $\mathcal{C}$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}_b(E;\mathbb{K})$ with respect to the supremum norm.

Ok, I really do not understand the hint: Any algebra is a vector space. Even a one-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is not countable anymore.

Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Maybe the author intended "construct a separable algebra"?

Comment: Or - what amounts to the same - "a countably generated algebra".